# Request last hour data from Big Query with Standard SQL

Tags: google-bigquery

This is my problem.

- I would like to request only the data of the last hour from Big Query.
- I would like to use Standard Sql.
- I would like to pay only for read the data in this interval of time.

Example :
My partition of the day take 200 Go. I request data of the last hour (40Go). Is it possible to pay only for 40Go in Standard SQL ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`table decorators`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators) (specifically [`range decorators`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#range_decorators)) but they are supported in BigQuery Legacy SQL ONLY

To get data from the last hour you can use below:

```
SELECT <list_of_fields> 
FROM [yourproject:yourdataset.yourtable@-3600000-]
```

Of course, the preferred query syntax for BigQuery is standard SQL - so you can either have your query logic built with Legacy SQL syntax and thus have whole logic in one query or you can use split logic to first get last hour data into temp table using legacy's sql decorators and then use standard sql to apply needed logic

Meantime see below opened issue on Google's Issue Tracker:
[`Support an equivalent to table decorators in standard SQL`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905931)
From that thread - looks like the closest feature to meet your case could be hourly partitioning - whenever it will be available